# SoX wav sound playback

Tags: audio, wav, playback

I tried this:

```
sox -u -r 11.025k -b 8 -c 1 infile.wav outfile.wav
```

But the sound is garbled and unrecognizable when I play it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sox -t wav infile.wav -r 11025 -b 8 -c 1 outfile.wav
```

The way you put it, the parameters get applied to `infile.wav`, not to `outfile.wav`.